# Haskell list comprehension, adding a string between two strings

Tags: string, list, haskell, list-comprehension

I am having trouble with a couple list problems. The first is supposed to insert a string between strings, as long as the strings are the same length, ie inserts "da" [("so","ed"),("c",""),("",""),("mo","le")] would return ["sodaed" "da" "modale"]

so far I have

```
inserts :: String -> [(String, String)] -> [String]
inserts str pairs = [[x,str,z] | (x,z) <- pairs, length (x) == length (z)]

inserts' :: String -> [(String, String)] -> [String]
inserts' [] [] = []
inserts' str [(x:xs),(y:ys)] 
    | (length y) == (length x) = (x, str, y) : inserts' str [xs,ys]
    | otherwise = inserts' str [x,ys]
```

I am getting a type error though matching [char] to string

Comment: Can you post the actual error message you're getting?

Answer (score 2):

You're really close! I'm pretty sure the error message you're getting is something different than not being able to match `[Char]` and `String` though, because these are the same!

Let's see what happens when we remove the type signature on `inserts` (I'm doing this in ghci, but you can of course try it via a file as well):

```
Prelude> let inserts str pairs = [[x,str,z] | (x,z) <- pairs, length x == length z]
Prelude> :t inserts
inserts :: [a] -> [([a], [a])] -> [[[a]]]
```

OK, that's a pretty general type. As you might know, `String` is the same as `[Char]`. So if we substitute `Char` for `a` in the type of `inserts`, and replace `[Char]` by `String`, we can see that the `inserts` can specialize to `String -> [(String,String)] -> [[String]]`.

So the arguments match, but the result has one level of lists too many. That's pretty logical, since `x`,`str` and `z` are strings, so `[x,str,z]` is a list of strings. All that's needed is to concatenate these three strings into one.

Either you can append the lists 'by hand', using `x ++ str ++ z` as the expression on the left side of the list comprehension, or you could use `concat [x,str,z]` to do it; `concat` flattens a list of lists (of `Char`acters in this case) into a list.

---

For your second try, you can use something similar instead of the three-tuple of strings `(x, str, y)`, do you see what you need to do?

Answer (score 0):

For the type to be correct, I think for the first function should be:

```
inserts :: String -> [(String, String)] -> [String]
inserts str pairs = [x ++ str ++z | (x,z) <- pairs, length (x) == length (z)]
```

or

```
inserts :: String -> [(String, String)] -> [[String]]
inserts str pairs = [[x,str,z] | (x,z) <- pairs, length (x) == length (z)]
```

, depending on your needs.